# ASP.NET Core HttpContext.Session.Clear() not clearing Session properly when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

**Languages:** C# and HTML Razor inside ASP.NET Core MVC

**Context/Issue;** I am storing user-specific information using HttpContext.Session, when debugging in Visual Studio calling HttpContext.Session.Clear() in my logout action functions as expected and clearing all Session variables. But when publishing and deploying the same app to IIS, clicking logout, the Session variables *are cleared*, but after approximately 10 - 12 seconds the Session variables re-appear like they never were cleared... There are also sometimes instances though where the Session does stay cleared, but a majority of the time it has this issue.

This results in the logout button logging the user out for about 10 seconds, then the user information re-appears thus making the website see the user as logged in again.

**Snips from my code:**

**Home Controller:**

```
        [Route("logout")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Logout()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**cshtml/Razor view/page:**

```
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout"><b>Logout</b></a>
```

**FYI:** I am using a this SessionExtension I found online that allows me to store objects directly in Session without me having to encode/decode them manually. I store the user info as a Dictionary so I can easily access it via HttpContextAccessor in pages to pull permissons when needed. I chose this rather then accessing the database everytime a permission is needed for a page. Instead accessing the database once when logging in and storing the gathered info in Session. I'm not sure if this is somehow causing it but I figured I'd include this bit for more context.

**SessionExtensions.cs :**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
#nullable enable
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
{
    public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static void SetObject(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the only issue I'm getting with Session, everything else works fine between users at the same time, just logging out is the issue. When the logout button does work everything else works fine too.

**Things I've Tried:**

Debugging the deployed instance on IIS with VS, the Session stays cleared (returns Null) for about 10 - 12 seconds after clicking the logout button, then everything re-appears like it was never cleared.

Debugging the project on my dev. computer inside VS and not seeing the same behavior, after clicking logout Session stays cleared indefinitely. (Returns Null)

Clearing cookies of client browser.

Restarting Server running IIS and site.

Deleting site from IIS and retransferring published files, then adding it again. Did the same with configuration for the publish set to Debug and Release. No change in functionality.

Updating all NuGet packages and also recently updating to .NET 7.0 framework.

I might be missing something as I'm pretty new to C#, ASP.NET Core MVC, and Razor pages, and even Stack Overflow. Comment if more information needs added to help answer the question.

**EDIT:**
The session timeout (Idle Timeout) set in Program.cs *always* correctly clears the session.

**EDIT:**
I could probably fix this by setting every session variable to null when clicking logout. But this seems like a run-around way of doing it and could be prone to errors if I add another variable in the future. Should this be the solution?

**EDIT:**
My previously mentioned fix of setting each variable to null doesn't solve every issue. I'm actually noticing other issues arising with session. I can't pinpoint because its random, sometimes setting a session variable doesn't take, or sometimes it does, or sometimes it does temporarily...

It's seeming almost like session is just ignoring some calls to it's methods, or when it follows them it only takes effect for 10 seconds...

**EDIT:**
I've tried everything I could try to fix this issue, until I stumbled across this.

```
@{var IPAddress = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();


Ping pingSender = new Ping();
PingReply reply1 = pingSender.Send(IPAddress);
PingReply reply2 = pingSender.Send(IPAddress);
PingReply reply3 = pingSender.Send(IPAddress);

long[] ReplyTimes = { reply1.RoundtripTime, reply2.RoundtripTime, reply3.RoundtripTime};}
@ReplyTimes
```

This is a small piece of code I setup in a debug page that would give me my current ping over an average of 3 samples. For some reason removing this code solved all my issues that I can tell so far. After further research it seemed like every time a session update took place (changing a variable) it would save the change then revert back after 10 seconds.

The weird part comes in where after another 10 seconds it would sometimes revert back again, to the latest variable, then repeat... Basically causing the variable to change by itself. This debug page only shows when logged in so I'm still a bit confused as to how this code on this page effected the ability to logout (The session clearing then re-appearing after 10 seconds even with the debug page not loaded)

I double checked and there was still only 1 session cookie the entire time.

I have no idea why removing this code fixed the issue. Maybe somehow accessing the request remote ip address causes unforeseen issues?

I'm adding this as an edit rather then a answer since this doesn't really answer why this is causing session to act the way it is.

Comment: Have you tried other methods? For example, Session.Abandon(), it is not only to delete session items, the session ID will also be deleted, will you still got the same problem?

Comment: @samwu There is no Session.Abandon() in ASP.NET Core MVC, this is present in ASP.NET but not core. The general equivalent is HttpContext.Session.Clear(); although this only clears the information in the session, not the session itself.

Comment: @samwu I added another edit at the very bottom, this seems like a janky solution to fix a problem that shouldn't be happening but I just thought of it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#session-state

Comment: @Jodrell Thanks for linking the documentation. It seemed like samwu was thinking of asp.net. Quote from the docs; "Session data is deleted either when the **ISession.Clear** implementation is called or when the session expires."

Comment: I've discovered this isn't isolated to the Session.clear() method but rather anytime a change takes place with a previously set session. I've noticed other variables that change sometimes don't take, or when they do it's temporary.